# Probability x will happen out of two tries?

Tags: probability

Say you grab a card out a deck, check it, and put it back.

If the probability of getting a non-club card is $\frac{3}{4}$, what is the probability it will happen at least once out of two tries?

You can't just multiply it by $2$ because it can't be $>1$, so what do you do?

Comment: A really good way to work through these sorts of problems is with tree diagrams. https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 possible scenarios:

1. It happens at the first try (probability of $\frac{3}{4}$). Then it doesn't matter if you try again
2. It doesn't happen the first try, but on the second try.
3. It doesn't happen the first try, and also not on the second try.

The probability that either 2. or 3. occurs is $1-\frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$, i.e. that you got a club card on the first try.

*Given that* this is the case, the probability of getting non-club again is $\frac{3}{4}$.

So the overall probability of getting non-club either on the first try, or non on the first try but on the second try, is:
$\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{4} = \frac{15}{16} \approx 0.9375$

$\frac{3}{4} \times \frac{3}{4} = \frac{9}{16}$ would be the probability you get a non-club card twice. (And not just at least once, so stronger criterion with lower probability).

Comment: Wait why would the probability be $3/4*3/4=9/16$ ? So I guess the probability scen3 happens is $1/4^2$, so thats $1/16$, then the probability of either scen1 or 2 happening is $1 - 1/16 = 15/16$.

And if you go by working out scen1 and then 2. Scen1 is $3/4$ (= $12/16$), scen2 is $1/4*3/4 = 3/16$. Then you add them together to get $15/16$ again.

OK that makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**:

Ways in which you can draw at least one club

$\mathbb{P}($draw non club on the first card, then non club on second $)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{9}{16}$

$\mathbb{P}($draw non club on the first card, then club on second$)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{16}$

$\mathbb{P}($draw club on first card, then non club on second$)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{16}$

So total probability is:

$\mathbb{P}($probability at least one club drawn$)=\frac{9}{16}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{3}{16}=\frac{15}{16}$

---

**Method 2**:

One can also notice that this probability is $1-\mathbb{P}($club drawn both times$)$

$\mathbb{P}($club drawn both times$)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{16}$

So, $\mathbb{P}($probability at least one club drawn$)=1-\frac{1}{16}=\frac{15}{16}$

Comment: Funny you should answer 1 minute too late